# Vite library mode code splitting with UMD like in webpack

Tags: webpack, vite

Is there a way to enable code-splitting in Vite for libraries like webpack does?

This is my current setup

```
import {fileURLToPath, URL} from 'node:url';
import {resolve} from 'path';
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    optimizeDeps: {
        force: true
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    },
    build: {
        outDir: resolve(__dirname, 'some/path'),
        emptyOutDir: true,
        lib: {
            entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/main.ts'),
            name: 'Site',
            formats: ['umd'],
            fileName: 'site',
        },
    },
});
```

and it won't automatically code split my files - instead it only creates one single file.
Only if I change `formats: ['umd'],` to `formats: ['cjs'],` it will work. However I would like to use `umd` mode

I made a minimal production repo: https://github.com/Anubarak/vite-code-splitting.
If someone is able to produce multiple output JS files instead of just one with `umd` please let me know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that's impossible, when I forced `dynamicInlineImports: false` I'd got an error:

`Invalid value "umd" for option "output.format" - UMD and IIFE output formats are not supported for code-splitting builds`

Comment: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/10609